# ValueError: Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

**DOESN'T WORK**:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import numpy as np

ipt = Input(shape=(4,))
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(ipt)

model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy')

X = np.random.randn(32,4)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(32,1))
model.train_on_batch(X,Y)
```

**WORKS**: remove `.python` from above's imports.

What's the deal, and how to fix?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:

- CUDA 10.0.130, cuDNN 7.4.2, Python 3.7.4, Windows 10
- `tensorflow`, `tensorflow-gpu` v2.0.0, and Keras 2.3.0 via pip, all else via Anaconda 3
- Per DEBUG 1, I note `pip` installs the `r2.0` branch rather than `master`; manually overwriting local `tensorflow_core.python` folder with `master`'s breaks everything - but doing so for a select-few files doesn't, though error persists

---

**DEBUG 1: files difference**

This holds for my local installation, rather than TF's Github branches `master` or `r2.0`; Github [files](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras/api) lack `api/_v2` for some reason:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
print(keras.__file__)
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__file__)
```

```py
[1] D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py
[2] D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\__init__.py
```

Looking into each `__init__` for `Optimizer`:

```py
# [1]
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.optimizer_v2 import OptimizerV2 as Optimizer
# [2]
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers

# in python.keras.optimizers.py:
# all imports are from tensorflow.python
class Optimizer(object): # <--- does NOT use optimizer_v2 for Optimizer
```

This appears to root the problem, as below works:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
```

This is strange, however, as the direct `import keras` doesn't use `optimizer_v2` either, though the definition of `Optimizer` in `keras.optimizers` does differ.

---

**DEBUG 2: execution difference**

Debugging side-by-side, while both use the same [training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1008), execution diverges fairly quickly:

```py
### TF.KERAS
    if self._experimental_run_tf_function: #  TRUE
### TF.PYTHON.KERAS
    if self._experimental_run_tf_function: #  FALSE
```

Former proceeds to call `training_v2_utils.train_on_batch(...)` and returns thereafter, latter `self._standardize_user_data(...)` and others before ultimately failing.

---

**DEBUG 3 (+ solution?): the fail-line**

```py
if None in grads: # <-- in traceback
```

Inserting `print(None in grads)` right above it yields the exact same error - thus, it appears related to TF2 iterable ops -- this works:

```py
if any([g is None for g in grads]): # <-- works; similar but not equivalent Python logic
```

Unsure yet if it's a complete fix, still debugging -- **update**: started a Github [Pull Request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33097)

---

**Full error trace**:

```py
  File "<ipython-input-1-2db039c052cf>", line 20, in <module>
    model.train_on_batch(X,Y)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1017, in train_on_batch
    self._make_train_function()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2116, in _make_train_function
    params=self._collected_trainable_weights, loss=self.total_loss)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 653, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 92, in get_gradients
    if None in grads:
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1336, in tensor_equals
    return gen_math_ops.equal(self, other)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 3626, in equal
    name=name)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf2_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 545, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))

ValueError: Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question. Regarding the "DEBUG 3": `None in grads` and `any([g is None for g in grads])` is substantially different (unless you know the type of `grads` as well as every `g` during iteration). `None in grads` is equivalent to `grads.__contains__(None)` and even when falling back on `__iter__` it will check for equality (`==`) not identity (`is`). Could you please clarify what the type of `grads` is? Also it is not clear what exactly your question is. It seems more like you should submit an issue.

Comment: @a_guest @a_guest grads are `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>` objects, and fair regarding any([.... The full error trace was linked in "ADDITIONAL INFO" - now included at bottom. Lastly, what's unclear about the question? I cite the exact error and include reproducible code.

Comment: Could you please also indicate `type(grads)` for completeness. Apparently `None in grads` triggers an `__eq__` comparison with the `Tensor` objects and this in turn attempts to convert the operand to a `Tensor` which fails. I.m.o. this is a bug and as such should be reported on their bug tracker. Regarding the question is seems you already found a way around the problem: using `tensorflow.keras` instead of `tensorflow.python.keras`. I'm not a heavy user of tensorflow so could you remind me what the `tensorflow.python` sub-package is good for anyway?

Comment: @a_guest These are actually `type()` outputs - and to be honest, I may open a separate question on your exact question (`tf.python.keras` vs `tf.keras`) - I don't know, but there are substantial implementation differences in source code. I've seen code samples use either - but since I strive to maximize compatibility for my [implementation](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw), I need to make it work for `tf.python.keras` as well. I'll start a PR within a day if noone offers a definitive fix (other than rewriting the source as I have).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I'm also confused by `tensorflow.python.keras` and `tensorflow.keras` after reading your question. Agree on opening a question on this.

Comment: @zihaozhihao [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)

Comment: @a_guest May interest you also: [tf.python.keras vs tf.keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug, and my [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33097) fix was approved (but isn't yet merged). In the meantime, you can make the change manually, [as here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33097/files#diff-bfba746b141112f6e8f852c873e01b84R92). Also, `tf.python.keras` isn't always meant to be used, if [at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras).

**UPDATE**: the pull request is now [merged](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33097).

---

**Why it works**: `None in grads` is same as `any(g == None for g in grads)`; problem is, `g` may be a tf.Tensor/tf.Variable which has [`.__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) defined only to operate on tensors, so `is None` must be used instead.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

ipt = Input((16,))
out = Dense(16)(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')

x = y = np.random.randn(32, 16)
model.train_on_batch(x, y)

W = model.optimizer.weights
W[0] == None
```

```
>>> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type 
    (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Checking source code:

```py
from inspect import getsource
print(getsource(W[0].__eq__))
```

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    """Compares two variables element-wise for equality."""
    if ops.Tensor._USE_EQUALITY and ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
        return gen_math_ops.equal(self, other, incompatible_shape_error=False)
    else:
        # In legacy graph mode, tensor equality is object equality
        return self is other
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should correct your imports

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
```